unity, quad size scalling and positioning to represent selection box
I need to show a highlighted area on a grid. The grid is just a grid object assigned to a gameobject and represented with shader graph material to visualize grids. The grid part can be ignored for this problem.
Now to mimic highlighting, I am using a quad since its size scales to exact 1 unit. But I am unsure how to set its position correctly as it is showing some offset. I want to start the quads top left corner to start from mouse start position as normal selection box does. Here is the code:
private void ResizeSelectionBox()
{
    //controlledVisualization is the quad assigned;
    Vector3 StartMousePosition = ...;
    float width = Input.mousePosition.x - StartMousePosition.x;
    float height = Input.mousePosition.y - StartMousePosition.y;

    // Calculate the actual width and height based on the positions
    float actualWidth = Mathf.Abs(width);
    float actualHeight = Mathf.Abs(height);

    // Set the transform's position and scale of the quad
    controlledVisualization.transform.position = StartMousePosition / quadSizeUnit;
    //scale is not right. need height and width.
    controlledVisualization.transform.localScale = new Vector3(actualWidth, actualHeight, 1f)/quadSizeUnit;

}


I think the problem here might be that the quad vertices usually are centered around (0,0) (top left (-1, 1), top right (1, 1) bottom left (-1, -1) bottom right (1, -1)). Therefore your quad position would be your mouse start position + actualWidth / 2 and actualHeight / 2 and it's scale also actualWidth / 2 and actualHeight / 2.
